# Python Beautiful Soup scrape website giving forbidden error 403

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape jobs from indeed using beautiful soup only(not selenium), am facing forbidden error 403. below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time as t

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
       
links_list = []
for current_page in range(1, 3):
        print(f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=UAE&start={current_page}')
        r = s.get(f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=UAE&start={current_page}') 
        page_num = (f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=UAE&start={current_page}')  
   
        #mosaic-provider-jobcards > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.slider_container.css-g7s71f.eu4oa1w0 > div > div.slider_item.css-kyg8or.eu4oa1w0 > div > table.jobCard_mainContent.big6_visualChanges > tbody > tr > td > div.css-1m4cuuf.e37uo190 > h2

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a')
        for link in links: 
             try:
                 url = link.select_one('a').get('href')
                 print(url)
                 r = s.get(f'{url}')
                 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
                 try:
                    title = soup.select_one(' div.jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title-container > h1').text.strip() 
                 except Exception as e:
                   title = ''
                 links_list.append((url, title))
                 print(f'done {title}----{url}---{page_num} ')
                 t.sleep(1)
             except Exception as e:
                 print(e)
                 
df = pd.DataFrame(links_list, columns = ['URL','Job Title', 'Company','Job Description','Job Application'])
df.to_csv('uae.csv')
```

I have tried to use User Agent but not solving anything.

Comment: have a look at the `https://ae.indeed.com/robots.txt` politic

Comment: Hi @cards, so many disallowed, so what can I do?, am a newbie. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, blockers can be evaded with modules [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) like, but these ones are too good. I tend to use [ScrapingAnt](https://scrapingant.com/) or [selenium](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) when this happens - I have 2 functions ([`linkToSoup_scrapingAnt`](https://pastebin.com/5ibz2F6p) and [`linkToSoup_selenium`](https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK)) which make it more convenient to use them with `BeautifulSoup`. You could make use of them in your code:

```py
### PASTE FOR linkToSoup_scrapingAnt FROM https://pastebin.com/5ibz2F6p 
### OR PASTE FOR linkToSoup_selenium FROM https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK 

roorUrl = 'https://ae.indeed.com'
for current_page in range(1, 3):
        page_url = f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=UAE&start={current_page}'
        print(page_url)

        # r = s.get(f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=UAE&start={current_page}')  
        # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        ## INSTEAD:

        # pgSoup = linkToSoup_scrapingAnt(page_url, isv=True, returnErr=False) # OR
        pgSoup = linkToSoup_selenium(page_url, isv=True, returnErr=False)
        if not pgSoup: continue

        links = [a.get('href') for a in pgSoup.select('a[id^="job_"][href]')]
        for link in links: 
             if link[:1] == '/': link = f'{roorUrl}{link}'
             # soup = linkToSoup_scrapingAnt(link, isv=True, returnErr=False) # OR
             soup = linkToSoup_selenium(link, isv=True, returnErr=False) 
             if not soup: continue

             ####### EXTRACT DATA #######
             # try...soup.select_one....text.strip()...except...
             # links_list.append(....) # print(f'done ....') # t.sleep(1)

# df = pd.DataFrame....df.to_csv....
```

Since it looks like you need to scrape quite a few pages, and ScrapingAnt only allows 1000 request a month (or even less, if you want to use their proxies) in the free tier, I'd recommend using selenium if you can.

---

Btw, if you're going to be using *`try...select...text`* repeatedly, you might also want to check out my [`selectForList`](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u) function.